# Building a multithreaded work-queue (consumer/producer) in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, deque

I have the following scenario: I have a single thread that is supposed to fill a
container with pairs of integers (in essence, task descriptions), and I have a large
number of worker threads (8-16) that should take elements from this container and perform
some work.

I thought the problem could be easily solved by a blocking queue -- e.g. on item-removal, threads synchronize access to the queue, and sleep if there is no data available.

I (perhaps wrongly) assumed that something like this should exist in the STL or in boost, but I was unable to find anything.

Do I actually have to implement that thing myself ? It seems like such a common scenario...

Answer (score 4):

If you do implement it yourself, the implementation should be a fairly straightforward combination of a semaphore, a mutex, and a queue object.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
Produce{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue.push_back(someObjectReference);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    sem_post(&availabilitySem);
}

Consume{
    sem_wait(&availabilitySem);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue.pop_front(someObjectReference);
    pthread_mutext_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

Comment: worth noting that, depending on your semaphore implementation, the Consume process may need to run inside of a loop

Answer (score 2):

If you are on windows take a look at the agents library in VS2010 this is a core scenario.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627(VS.100).aspx

i.e.

```
//an unbounded_buffer is like a queue
unbounded_buffer<int> buf;

//you can send messages into it with send or asend
send(buf,1);

//receive will block and wait for data
int result = receive(buf)
```

you can use threads, 'agents' or 'tasks' to get the data out... or you can link buffers together and convert your blocking semantic producer / consumer problem to a data flow network.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows and want a queue that is efficient in terms of how it manages the threads that are allowed to run to process items from it then take a look at IO Completion Ports (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx)). My [free server framework](http://www.serverframework.com/products---the-free-framework.html) includes a task queue implementation that's based on IOCPs and that may also be of interest if you intend to go down this route; though it's possibly too specialised for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`message_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue.html) from [`boost::interprocess`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html) is what you want. The second link has a usage example.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ACE (Adaptive Communication Environment)](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html) and the ACE_Message_Queue.  There's always boost's [message_queue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1%5F35%5F0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message%5Fqueue.html), but ACE is where it's at in terms of high performance concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on OSX Snow Leopard, you might want to look at [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch).